# Will local variables declared in a Java function automatically be deallocated?

Tags: java, function, memory, scope, allocation

If a variable is declared within a function in Java, will that variable be deallocated automatically upon that function's completion regardless of its type? Would the memory occupied by a primitive type, a non-primitive `Object`, and/or an `array` of either primitives or `Objects` be freed up once that variable's scope has been exited?

Comment: Immediately? Perhaps, but not likely. Always? Depends, not when there's still a reference to it somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Primitive types in Java are allocated on the stack, so their memory is automatically deallocated when they go out of scope. Object references are primitives which are similarly managed, but the objects themselves are garbage collected. They will be removed automatically by the garbage collector, but it is not guaranteed how long that will take.

The JVM garbage collector automatically runs when the memory pressure becomes tight, so as long as there are no references to an object anymore, you can effectively make the assumption that its memory will be freed.

Comment: So basically I don't need to worry much about it taking up space on the heap and overloading it once the program is running out of its scope, is that correct?

Comment: @user2649681 Yes, for the most part, the garbage collector will handle memory management for you. Of course, allocating a massive number of objects will still be slow, but that's not due to Java's memory management. That's just because massive amounts of allocation and deallocation will be slow no matter how your language manages memory.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no reference to the object, Garbage collector will remove it automatically. But we cant say when will that happen.

This [article](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx) have a pretty good explanation about how garbage collector works.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Allexis King's Answer

there is one more technique in newer Java/ JVM which decides whether local object should be allocated in Stack or Heap. local objects allocated in stack by this technique will be de-allocated when it goes out of scope

Escape Analysis

Escape analysis is a technique by which the Java Hotspot Server Compiler can analyze the scope of a new object's uses and decide whether to allocate it on the Java heap.

Escape analysis is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23 and later.